# Converting a decimal (user string) into hex with 0x prefix

Tags: c#, winforms, hex, decimal, data-conversion

I am trying to take a user defined decimal value from a textBox, convert to a hex (with the 0x) prefix then store that value to an integer. I'm currently stuck at getting the 0x prefix, but maybe there is a more appropriate way to accomplish this.

```
        string decimalString = textBox1.Text;

        //Convert decimalString string into an int
        int decimalNumber = int.Parse(decimalString);
        //Convert decimalNumber to a hex string
        string hexString = decimalNumber.ToString("X");

        Console.Write(decimalNumber);

        //TextBox Input: 151
        //Console Output: 97
        //Desired Output: 0x97 (as a string, but would like to assign to int if possible).
        int finalDesiredOutput = 0x97;
```

Hope I am explaining this well.

In this project I'm trying to replace the 13th byte in a header with a decimal value between 0-2600 (user entered value). It's easier for a user to enter a decimal as opposed to a hex value (i.e. 2600, rather than A28).

Comment: `int` numbers are just numbers, once they are in computer memory they don't have a particular base (well, they do, Base-2). You write your code either specifying base-10 or base-16 (hex). So really your `finalDesiredOutput` can just be set to `decimalNumber`, no need to convert it to hex and then "store" it in an `int`.

Comment: The "0x" concat is a real face palm moment for me. Clearly I've spent too much time in front of the computer today. Second answer is a light bulb moment. Thanks for both answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about `String.Format()`

```
 string hexString =String.Format("0X{0:X}", decimalNumber);
```

Comment: simplier: string.Format("0X{0:X}", decimalNumber)

Comment: how to do it with int?

Comment: @Faisal: I don't get your question, in case of int why you need decimal formatting?

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

string hex = "C26B3CB3833E42D8270DC10C";


for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length; i++)
{
    if(i%2==0)
    {
         sb.Append(",0x").Append(hex.Substring(i, 2));
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/360251/edit) your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made. [ref](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360251/8371915)